# How to save a list/array to an object

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist

I just started using Apex and Visualforce and I have a question regarding how to save a list to an object.

I currently have an Asset object which contains information about a particular asset built from a product. Assets have a list of options which they can contain. Ie. a specific Hamburger is being made, it can have pickles, onions, etc... Hamburger being the product, 10th one being made is the specific asset.

I have an Options multi-picklist on my Asset, I've statically entered a bunch of possible options, which worked fine, I could create my asset and pick my options from a huge list.

But what I've done now, is I'm dynamically populating a list of options based on what type of product the asset is going to be. A milkshake product will have the options 'Chocolate', and 'Vanilla' but not 'Pickles' and 'Onions' and those options will have a list of ingredients.

I'll write some pseudo code below:

```
public class AssetControllerExtension
{
    private final Asset asset;
    private Options__c[] selectedOptions = new...

    public AssetControllerExtension()
    {
        this.asset = new Asset();
    }

    public List<SelectOption> AvailableOptions
    {
        //return a list of available options
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        //this does not work
        asset.Options = selectedOptions;
        insert asset;
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help, please let me know if I'm not being clear or my code example is insufficient, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom multi-select picklist can store up to 150 values of up to 40 characters each. So if the number of options fits within those limits you could consider just storing the option names directly on a custom multi-select picklist field you add to Asset. (And you might be able to use record types to manage the sub-sets for various types of Asset.) The `apex:selectList` can then just be bound directly to that field and the data would be saved when the Asset is saved.

If instead you want a separate (child) object for the options, then make the value of the multiselect `apex:selectList` a simple string field (called `selectedOptions` in the code below) and in the `Save` method insert the child objects:

```
public void Save() {

    // Id will be assigned by the insert
    insert asset;

    Option__c[] options = new Option__c[] {};
    for (String option : selectedOptions.split(';')) {
        options.add(new Option__c(Name = option, Asset__c = asset.Id);
    }
    insert options;
}
```